# Cannot coerce to a table when doing correlation

Tags: r, correlation

I have a 33 rows list data,
as below:

[enter link description here](https://rit0-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/jc3992_rit_edu/EYlFbp4igjdLgHE2d8wUcBMBSHgNOycsZdcOYAl4HbN2Xg?e=MUJgn3)

And I was using the code as below to create a correlation coefficient:

```
    mpg.df <- as.data.frame(mpg)

cor(mpg, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
```

However, I am getting the same error:

> Error in cor(mpg, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs") : 
>     'x' must be numeric

And I used typeof(mpg.df), the result was "list" still.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your example data frame has one or more columns that are not numeric. Since your example data frame looks like a subset of the pre-defined `mtcars` data frame in R, I will just create this subset in R as follows.

```
# Select some columns
mtcars2 <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt")]

# View the first six rows 
head(mtcars2)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460
```

Now take a look at the structure `mtcars2`, you can see that all columns are numeric.

```
# Show the class of each column
str(mtcars2)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  6 variables:
#   $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
# $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
# $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
# $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
```

Since all columns are numeric, we can thus use the `cor` function to do correlation analysis.

```
# Do correlation analysis
cor(mtcars2)
#             mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt
# mpg   1.0000000 -0.8521620 -0.8475514 -0.7761684  0.6811719 -0.8676594
# cyl  -0.8521620  1.0000000  0.9020329  0.8324475 -0.6999381  0.7824958
# disp -0.8475514  0.9020329  1.0000000  0.7909486 -0.7102139  0.8879799
# hp   -0.7761684  0.8324475  0.7909486  1.0000000 -0.4487591  0.6587479
# drat  0.6811719 -0.6999381 -0.7102139 -0.4487591  1.0000000 -0.7124406
# wt   -0.8676594  0.7824958  0.8879799  0.6587479 -0.7124406  1.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry I am able to log on to check out on this today. I remembered the data set "mtcars" is a data frame itself. What if I have a data set which is a "list"? Would your first subset still works? because "Corr" function can only apply on matrix or data frame, based on what I have searched for. If the subset is still a list (typeof()=list), may I still use this way to create a correlation? Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Jen-LiChen The first argument to the `cor` function should be a matrix or data frame. However, it should not be a problem for you to convert your list to a data frame. If you type `typeof(mtcars)`, you will notice that `mtcars` is not only a data frame, but also a list. In fact, data frame in R is a list.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you very much!!